# PayPal IPN Problem

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-processing

This is really basic but:

If I send an IPN test (via the PayPal IPN test tool) to a script url that simply triggers a generic email to me.

Shouldn't that send me an email?

I just want to make sure that I am not ignorant about something simple here. But If PayPal is really touching that script, it should fire off the email right?

PayPal IPN test tool says it is getting a failure and describing it as a code 500. But my host says ports are open and working fine. I can browse to my script with a browser and it triggers the email.

Any ideas what I am missing?

The code in my listener is simply one line that sends me an email:

```
<?php
    mail($this->tech_email,'Requested Before POSTBACK',"Here you go");
?>
```

I am just trying to make sure PayPal is actually calling this url. Doesn't appear to be.

Comment: Ask your host for details about the 500 error - that is clearly a problem on your script's end

Comment: The Paypal IPN test tool is a very simple one. It just creates an HTTP POST message to the url you provide. Error 500 is typically an application error. It can be on Paypal's application or your application. We can't review Paypal's code, so we should start with yours. Can you post your listener code so we can take a look and see if we can find the problem?

Comment: PayPal's test tool simply reports back the HTTP status code it encounters when it accesses your script with all the (dummy) POST data. As jdias said, check your error logs and give us a peek at your code.

Comment: Well, I added my code. That one line is all there is. The 'tech_email' is basically a string containing the email address I am sending the message to.

Comment: And if you replace that by an actual email address and test it again? For debugging: KISS.